# How to iterate over numbers in C

Tags: c, loops, iteration

I've gotta count how many times a certain digit is repeated in each number in a range. For example, in the numbers between 0 and 20, there is only one occurrence of 1 being repeated twice (11). I originally did this by converting the int to a str and iterating over it, but I would like to be able to solve this in an arithmetic way. Any ideas?

Comment: Use `n % 10` to pick off rightmost digit, `n / 10` to eliminate the rightmost digit of `n`. Lather, rinse, repeat.

Answer (score 2):

You can divide your number multiple times by 10:

```
int number = 72;
int rest;

while(number)
{
    rest = number % 10;
    printf("%d\n", rest);
    number /= 10;
}
```

Here **rest** contains '2' and then '7'

Comment: but what if the rang is from 100 to 200 , and you have the number 121 , your code will fail this case

Comment: Why does it fail? you will have rest = 1, rest = 2 and then rest = 1

Comment: Minor quibble: The name `rest` implies it's all the leftovers after removing some small thing (when in fact it's the opposite, it's the small thing removed, and `number` ends up being cut down to the "rest"). Probably nicer to name it `digit` (more descriptive, less misleading). To be clear, this is a reasonable solution (I up-voted), this is just a nitpick.

Comment: If `number == 0`, this prints nothing.  OP's example talks of "numbers between 0 and 20".

Answer (score 1):

here is a general solution that you can use , your problem didn't contain much information so I assumed that you want to count the number of repeating of each digit in each number.

so what I did is like hashing where the digits in each number will never cross the value `9` , so they are from `0` to `9` so I made that hash table called `arr`, so what I did is to come to every single digit in number and increment the position of that digit in `arr`

for example , number `554` will cause `arr[5]++;` twice and `arr[4]++;` only once , simple idea of using hash tables.

and then at the end I iterate over the hash array printing the number of occurrence of each digit in each number.

and here is the code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{
    int arr[6] = {5555, 12112, 14, -3223, 44, 10001};

    int tempArr[10] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        int temp1 = arr[i];

        // get the number of occurrences of each digit in each number
        do{
            tempArr[(abs(temp1) % 10)]++;
            temp1 /= 10;
        }while(temp1 != 0);

        // loop over the array to know how many times each digit occurred
        printf("the number of occurrences in number called %d\n", arr[i]);
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            if(tempArr[j] > 1)
                printf("number %d occurred %d times\n", j, tempArr[j]);

            // resetting that position of the array
            tempArr[j] = 0;
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

and here is the output :

```
the number of occurrences in number called 5555
number 5 occurred 4 times
the number of occurrences in number called 12112
number 1 occurred 3 times
number 2 occurred 2 times
the number of occurrences in number called 14
the number of occurrences in number called -3223
number 2 occurred 2 times
number 3 occurred 2 times
the number of occurrences in number called 44
number 4 occurred 2 times
the number of occurrences in number called 10001
number 0 occurred 3 times
number 1 occurred 2 times
```

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica , yeah , I agree with , so I edited the code , instead of `while` , I used `do{ . . . } while( . . . );` , also instead of multiplying by -1 if the number is negative , I used the `abs()` function from the math header file , it's not the best thing but it's the best what can I do , thanks for revising.

Comment: `(abs(temp1) % 10)` is UB when `temp1==INT_MIN`.  OTOH, `(abs(temp1 % 10))` works for all `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Riffing on the answer provided by @Abdo Salm presented only to demonstrate a slightly alternative approach. All credit to Abdo.

EDIT: Going beyond single, arbitrary numbers to generating ascending contiguous sequence of numbers to be evaluated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>

void process( int n, int cnts[] ) {
    // count occurences of each digit (right to left)
    while( n )
        cnts[ abs(n % 10) ]++, n /= 10;
}

void report( int cnts[], int thresh ) {
    char *sep = "";
    for( int j = 0; j < 10; j++ )
        if( cnts[ j ] > thresh )
            printf( "%s%dx%d", sep, cnts[ j ], j ), sep = ", ";

    if( !*sep )
        printf( "no digit occurred multiple times" );

    putchar( '\n' );
}

int main() {
#ifndef PROVE
    int tests[] = {
        0, 11, 121, 5555, 12112, 14,
        -3223, 44, 1223334444,
        INT_MIN, INT_MAX,
    };

    // proof of concept: run through multiple arbitrary test values
    for( int i = 0; i < sizeof tests/sizeof tests[0]; i++ ) {
        // counter for each digit, all init'd to zero
        int cnts[ 10 ];
        memset( cnts, 0, sizeof cnts );

        process( tests[ i ], cnts );

        // report only digits appearing multiple times
        printf( "%11d: ", tests[ i ] );
        report( cnts, 1 );
    }
#else // with "ranges" instead of arbitrary test cases
    int ranges[][2] = {
        {   0,  10, },
        {   0,  22, },
        { 110, 133, },
        { 447, 448, },
    };

    for( int r = 0; r < sizeof ranges/sizeof ranges[0]; r++ ) {
        int metacnts[10];
        memset( metacnts, 0, sizeof metacnts );

        for( int i = ranges[r][0]; i <= ranges[r][1]; i++ ) {
            int cnts[ 10 ];
            memset( cnts, 0, sizeof cnts );

            process( i, cnts );

            for( int j = 0; j < 10; j++ )
                if( cnts[ j ] > 1 )
                    metacnts[ j ]++;
        }

        // report only digits appearing multiple times in numbers between min & max
        printf( "Range %3d-%3d (incl) ", ranges[r][0], ranges[r][1] );
        report( metacnts, 0 );
    }
#endif

    return 0;
}


/*
Output from arbitrary sequence:
          0: no digit occurred multiple times
         11: 2x1
        121: 2x1
       5555: 4x5
      12112: 3x1, 2x2
         14: no digit occurred multiple times
      -3223: 2x2, 2x3
         44: 2x4
 1223334444: 2x2, 3x3, 4x4
-2147483648: 3x4, 2x8
 2147483647: 3x4, 2x7

Output from arbitrary ranges:
Range   0- 10 (incl) no digit occurred multiple times
Range   0- 22 (incl) 1x1, 1x2
Range 110-133 (incl) 12x1, 1x2, 1x3
Range 447-448 (incl) 2x4
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

> how many times a certain digit is repeated in each number in a range.

**Pseudo code**<sup>*1</sup>

Get the range: `imin, imax`  (any `int` pair where `imin <= imax`)

Get the digit: `digit` 0 to 9

Iterate `m` from `imin` to `imax`, inclusive

.... Print `m`

.... Set `digit_count = 0`

.... Repeat

.......  Last digit `ld` of `m` is `abs(m%10)`.

.......  If `ld == digit`, increment `digit_count`.

........ Divide `m` by 10

.... Until `m == 0`

.... Print `digit_count`

Done

---

<sup>*1</sup> As OP did not provide code, seemed best to not provide a code answer.